# jquery hover or click functions not workig

Tags: jquery, hover, click, hide

```
$('#142').click(function(e)   // THIS CODE IS WORKING

{  
    alert(1);

    $('#143').hide();

 });                          // THIS CODE IS WORKING
```

This code works perfectly. 
When using `.click()` or `.hover()` instead of `.hide()` not working.

```
$('#142').click(function(e) {     // THIS CODE NOT WORKING


    alert(1);

    $('#143').click();

 });                          // THIS CODE NOT WORKING
```

Comment: What does not working mean here? You seeing any error in console?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask. Hint: Add some HTML and a working/non working example. ALso it is poor practice (though legal) to use numeric IDs

Comment: Hi void, There is no error. Hide functions is working well..but the click and hover functions not working..

Answer (score 0):

Use `.trigger()` instead of `.click()` to trigger a click as:

```
$( "#143" ).trigger( "click" );
```

trigger()  executes all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type. So that's why your click handler may not be working.

Read more about it from [here](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: sorry, its not working..actually its #142 is a menu and #143 is a submenu. Thank you for your prompt reply